# LinQ How to get all the data from the range of numbers

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to `LinQ` and I want to get all the data from a range of numbers when I pass a parameter. For an example, the range is 1-100 and I pass in `40`, it should get all the data from `1-100` but not only `40`. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList()` for getting all numbers between 1 and 100.

Comment: This question is off-topic for stackoverflow site. You should describe the problem and show what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Five answers! People keep encouraging such poor and lazy questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Enumerable.Range` which will give you range of numbers. You can use `Except` method to remove the numbers that you dont want.

```
private static int[] GetRange(int start,int inclusiveEnd,int[] except)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(start, inclusiveEnd - start + 1).Except(except).ToArray();
}
```

Then call it in this way.

```
var x = GetRange(1, 100, new[] {40});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use filtering (i.e. `Where` statement):

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(1,100).Where(x=>x != 40).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
var result = list.Where(i=> i >= 1 && i <= 100 && i != 40);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that there is a function, that transforms a number from given range into some data:

`Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Where(_ => _ != 40).Select(_ => GetData(_));`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Except` extension method [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb908822(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
List<int> oldList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int parameter = 2;
List<int> newList = oldList.Except(new int[] { parameter }).ToList<int>();
```